# Enlazar Typeform con R

Tags: r

Dispongo de un cuestionario en Typeform, lo he enlazado con google sheets, sin embargo, el objetivo es hacer que este proceso sea más automatizado. ¿Es posible enlazarlo directamente con R? o en caso de que se utilice Google Sheet ¿es posible que haya una especie de temporizador que permita descargar las respuestas del cuestionario a R?

Gracias!!

Comment: Bienvenida Maria Alejandra Ovalle a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Revisa este paquete: https://github.com/csgillespie/rtypeform posiblemente te ayude a lo que estás buscando.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

A pesar de que no hay un ejemplo específico del código que estás construyendo, creo que puede servirte consultar los paquetes [googledrive](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/googledrive/versions/2.0.0) y [googlesheets4](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/googlesheets4/versions/1.0.0) para importar y guardar hojas de cálculo almacenadas en Google Drive.

Para importar una hoja de cálculo de Google Drive de manera automatizada, necesitas:

1. Instalar el paquete googlesheets4,
2. Dar de alta tu usuario de Google Drive (en la primera ocasión te llevará a un proceso de autentificación para conectar con la API),
3. Importar la base con la dirección url de la base que deseas importar.

Un ejemplo genérico sería:

```
# Cargar la librería (una vez que ha sido instalada)     
library(googlesheets4) 

# Registrar el correo electrónico que tiene acceso a la base
gs4_auth("nombre@gmail.com")

# Importar la hoja de cálculo 
df_data <- googlesheets4::read_sheet("https;//docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXXX")
```

Cada vez corras este código, se estará importando la versión más reciente de documento, por lo que el paso de actualizar la información queda automatizado. Ojalá te sirva.